# Vertical scroll is actually horizontal scroll using mousewheel library

Tags: javascript, scroll, mousewheel

Example: http://mashup.ikm.gda.pl/

Here's the code I'm using right now:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#umm").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    
    event.preventDefault();

  });
});
```

```css
#umm {
width: 15em;
height: 5em;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
}

#thing {
width: 20em;
background-color: brown;
height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>

<div id="umm">
  <div id="thing"></div>
</div>
```

I want to make it so when you scroll the `#umm` box vertically it scrolls horizontally instead. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I reinserted the original link to the mousewheel library, which seemed to have been the issue. Now voting to close for simple mistake.

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Sorry to bother, but when I try to run the code now it provides an error message?

Comment: Yes, the link is now wrong but that's what you posted in the original example. I just made it into an embedded snippet, changing that link and with that accidentally solving the issue. Which was that `mousewheel.js` wasn't loaded at the lack of the correct link. It's not up to me to change the question like that so I reverted it.